# bash: Retrieving Android image filenames over adb shell

Tags: bash, adb

Here's a one-liner that is driving me nuts:

```
$ adb shell ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera | grep IMG_20150630|while read f; do echo "pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/$f"; done
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091806.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091817.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091819.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091822.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091842.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_175231:nopm:.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_175340:nopm:.jpg
pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_222520.jpg
```

Fine. Now I want to add something after `$f`:

```
$ adb shell ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera | grep IMG_20150630|while read f; do echo "pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/$f ./"; done
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091806.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091817.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091819.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091822.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_091842.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_175231:nopm:.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_175340:nopm:.jpg
 ./l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150630_222520.jpg
```

WTF?! The chars added after `$f` are actually added to the begining of every line.

Mac OS X 10.10.4, using GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)

Comment: Don't ever use `ls` in scripts: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Instead: `printf '%s\0' /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*`, to get a completely unambiguously parsable (NUL-delimited) list of names out.

Comment: `while read f` is buggy: It doesn't handle names with trailing spaces, doesn't handle names with literal backslashes, etc. Don't do that.

Comment: The target machine is an Android phone, it has very little support of GNU bin utils, so I'll have to rely on `ls` for this one. But you got a point.

Comment: `printf` is not binutils, it's POSIX sh, present in **any** compliant shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `while read line` actually ensures that I don't have trailing spaces issues. I just need to enclose `$line` in quotes inside the loop.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `read` implicitly trims trailing characters in IFS. Now, if you ran `IFS= read -r line`, *that* would be reliable.

Comment: Which is what I wanted.

Comment: What you want, if and only if your filenames don't actually **have** literal trailing characters.

Comment: As I said, it's a very narrow use case of Android pictures. I just wanted to understand the issue, which was a CR. I shouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: Also, I misunderstood 'trailing spaces' as 'inside spaces' a few comments up. My bad.

Comment: (`/usr/bin/printf` may be GNU coreutils, but if your shell is compliant, it'll also have a `printf` built-in; in fact, the POSIX spec explicitly notes `echo` as deprecated in favor for all nontrivial uses).

Comment: As a general rule if you have later line contents overwriting the start of the line you have a CR in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a CR. I guess that `adb` returns a CRLF for every line? Weird, there's no Windows involved here.

```
$ adb shell ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera | grep IMG_20150630|head -n 1 |xxd
0000000: 494d 475f 3230 3135 3036 3330 5f30 3931  IMG_20150630_091
0000010: 3830 362e 6a70 670d 0a                   806.jpg..
```

Comment: Not a newline, but a carriage return

Comment: The extra `\r` in `adb shell` output has been discussed many many times. Unfortunately it does not stop people from posting their own variation of the problem over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Using a NUL-delimited stream is the better approach for transporting arbitrary filenames over the wire. (Now, if you have `CR`s being transformed to `CRLF` somewhere in your stack, that's a separate issue -- but this will also avoid it, unless your filenames contain literal CRs).

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  printf 'pull %q\n' "$REPLY"
done < <(adb shell printf '%s\0' /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*IMG_20150630*)
```

The use of `%q` will also escape hidden characters in your output in a human-readable manner, making it easier to see what's going on if you have unusual behavior in the future.

Comment: There must be something missing because this doesn't output anything. Where's `$REPLY` declared/filled?

Comment: `REPLY` is the default variable name used by `read` on bash, if not given any other arguments.

Comment: That's what I guessed, however there is no output.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Android development kit is at home, and I'm at the office right now; I'll need to test and report back later.

Comment: The `adb` part just prints a list of files, I guess `\0`-separated. So you could test with just `"a\0b\0c\0d"`, I guess.

Comment: It *definitely* works correctly with `printf '%s\0' a b c d`. Meaning there's something more interesting going on, meaning I'd actually want to test it with adb in play.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. Meaning that `adb` is really a mess to work with.

Comment: Be interesting to look into whether the busybox on Android includes any tools for base64 encoding or uuencoding.

Comment: OK then, update your answer when you'll have time. Thanks a lot for your help and comments. Have a nice one.